# How do i do a row wise sum in SAS

Tags: sas, sum

I need to do a row wise sum of data using SAS. The data file looks like this

```
Dress_ID    29/8/2013   31/8/2013
1006032852  2114        2274
1212192089  151         275
1190380701  6           7
```

I want to sum the columns 29/8/2013 and 31/8/2013 as per the Dress_Id

Regards,

Aditya

Comment: Do you only have two columns, or are there more? Also does each `dress_id` only appear once? If it's just a few columns and `dress_id` appears only once, you can use `+` or `sum(col1, col2, ...)`

Comment: You could use PROC TRANSPOSE and sum the cols.  Also, a useful paper is "Using PROC SQL to Summarize and Transpose Data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is by using the `sum(of _NUMERIC_)` function. If you use this just make sure that you format Dress_ID as a character variable as this sums all numeric variables in a row. You may also run into some problems if you add additional numeric fields to you data set but as it stands now, this should solve your problems.

This can be written as:

```
data want;
  set have;
Total = sum(of _NUMERIC_);
run;
```

This will create a column "Total" in your data set with the totals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to do if you just have 2 variables in your dataset:

```
Proc Sql;
Create table Sum_table as 
Select Dress_id, Date1+date2 as sum_of_dates
from dataset_dress;
quit;
```

Date1 and Date2 are your 29/8/2013 and 31/8/2013. You cannot have variable names starting with date, However this is only for example if I am not wrong.