# Row-wise operation for subset of columns

Tags: sas

I have the following data:

```
data df;
input id $ d1 d2 d3;
datalines;
a . 2 3
b . . .
c 1 . 3
d . . .
;
run;
```

I want to apply some transformation/operation across a subset of columns. In this case, that means dropping all rows where columns prefixed with `d` are **all** missing/null.

Here's one way I accomplished this, taking heavy influence from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39660355/5015569).

First, sum all numeric columns, row-wise.

```
data df_total;
set df;
total = sum(of _numeric_);
run;
```

Next, drop all rows where `total` is missing/null.

```
data df_final;
set df_total;
where total is not missing;
run;
```

Which gives me the output I wanted:

```
a . 2 3
c 1 . 3
```

My issue, however, is that this approach assumes that there's only one "primary-key" column (`id`, in this case) and everything else is numeric and should be considered as a part of this `sum(of _numeric_) is not missing` logic.

In reality, I have a diverse array of other columns in the original dataset, `df`, and it's not feasible to simply `drop` all of them, writing all of that out. I know the columns for which I want to run this "test" all are prefixed with `d` (and more specifically, match the pattern `d<mm><dd>`).

How can I extend this approach to a particular subset of columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different short cut reference, since you know it all starts with D,

```
total = sum( of D:);
if n(of D:) = 0 then delete;
```

Which will add variables that are numeric and start with D. If you have variables you want to exclude that start with D, that's problematic.

Since it's numeric, you can also use the N() function instead, which counts the non missing values in the row. In general though, SAS will do this automatically for most PROCS such as REG/GLM(not in a data step obviously).

If that doesn't work for some reason you can query the list of variables from the sashelp table.

```
proc sql noprint;
select name into :var_list separated by ", " from sashelp.vcolumn
where libname='WORK' and memname='DF' and name like 'D%';
quit;

data df;
   set have;
   if n(&var_list.)=0 then delete;
run;
```